# InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.Models.Socios'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have a program in aspnet.core with login and logout. When I log in as a partner on the login page I have the "Teachers" layout that should show me the list of existing teachers.
This method is obtained in the layout as

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="Professores" asp-action="ListarProfessores">Professores</a>

</li>
```

This method is created in the Teachers driver, I add a list view with the teachers in the class.
In the Teachers answer list, I have this code:

```
       @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Professores>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ListarProfessores";
}

    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 0px;
            background-color: gray;
            background-image: url();
            background-image: url();
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>

<h1>Professores Registados</h1>


<table class="table" style="color:white">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>



            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>

                <td>

                    <a asp-controller="Socios" asp-action="EscolherPT" asp-route-id="@item.Idprofessor">Escolher PT</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can someone help me solve this please?

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.Models.Socios', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication1.Models.Professores]'

In the Teachers controller I have this method:

```
 public IActionResult ListarProfessores()
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId"));


        foreach (var item in _context.Socios)
        {
            if (item.Idsocio == x)
            {
                var y = item;
                return View(y);

            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

So I have two classes: the teachers class and the social class. When I am logged in as a partner I wanted to see a list of the teachers in the table and select one to be a personal trainer.
In the social class I have:

```
 public partial class Socios
    {
        public Socios()
        {
            Gerir = new HashSet<Gerir>();
            Mensagem = new HashSet<Mensagem>();
            Participa = new HashSet<Participa>();
            PersonalTrainer = new HashSet<PersonalTrainer>();
            Peso = new HashSet<Peso>();
            PlanosExercicios = new HashSet<PlanosExercicios>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("IDSocio")]
        public int Idsocio { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("email")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("telefone")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("fotografia")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Fotografia { get; set; }
        [Column("sexo")]
        public bool Sexo { get; set; } // true- Feminino
                                      //  false" - Masculino
        [Column("altura")]
        public double Altura { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("nome_utilizador")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string NomeUtilizador { get; set; }
        [Column("peso_inicial")]
        public double PesoInicial { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("_password")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Column("estado")]
        public int Estado { get; set; } // 1 ativo, 0 suspenso 

        //[Column("mensalidade")]
        //public bool Mensalidade { get; set; } //0-nao pago  1-pago

        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Gerir> Gerir { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Mensagem> Mensagem { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Participa> Participa { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalTrainer> PersonalTrainer { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Peso> Peso { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PlanosExercicios> PlanosExercicios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the teachers class I have:

```
public partial class Professores
    {
        public Professores()
        {
            MapaAulasGrupo = new HashSet<MapaAulasGrupo>();
            Mensagem = new HashSet<Mensagem>();
            PersonalTrainer = new HashSet<PersonalTrainer>();
            Peso = new HashSet<Peso>();
            PlanosExercicios = new HashSet<PlanosExercicios>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("IDProfessor")]
        public int Idprofessor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("nome")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("email")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column("telefone")]
        public int Telefone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("fotografia")]

        public string Fotografia { get; set; }
        [Column("sexo")]
        public bool Sexo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("especialidade")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Especialidade { get; set; }
        [Column("estado")]
        public int Estado { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("_password")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<MapaAulasGrupo> MapaAulasGrupo { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Mensagem> Mensagem { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalTrainer> PersonalTrainer { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Peso> Peso { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PlanosExercicios> PlanosExercicios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the Personal Trainer class I have:
Personal trainers are chosen by members through existing teachers

```
 [Table("Personal_trainer")]
    public partial class PersonalTrainer
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("IDProfessor")]
        public int Idprofessor { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column("IDSocio")]
        public int Idsocio { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column("Data_Pedido", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime DataPedido { get; set; }
        [Column("data_Inicio", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }
        [Column("data_fim", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Idprofessor))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Professores.PersonalTrainer))]
        public virtual Professores IdprofessorNavigation { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Idsocio))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Socios.PersonalTrainer))]
        public virtual Socios IdsocioNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of controller action?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  Yes of course, I edited the post and put it in the controller method

Comment: You're passing the class `Socios` to the view not a list of `Professores`. Perhaps `Socios` has a list of `Professores` as a member, if so you just need to replace `return View(y)` with `return View(y.Professores)`

Comment: @George Hello, I have separate classes, I have a socio class and a teacher class. And I wanted to present the list of teachers in the database when the partner is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs since that your controller code `return View(y)` returns a `Socio` model while your view receives `IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Professores>` as model.They are expected to be the same type.

> I have separate classes, I have a socio class and a teacher class.

Then we need to know the relationships between `Socio` and `Professores` (you'd better show all necessary models code and their relationships) and return list of `Professores`.

For example, if `Socio` has

```
public class Socio
{
   //other properties
   public List<Professores> Professores {get;set;}
}
```

Then use `return View(y.Professores);`

Comment: .Hello, I don't have a list in the class, I updated the publication with what I have in the classes.

Comment: @rsd_17 As I have said that, the action return type needs to be matched to receiving type of view.

Comment: How do I do that then?